# Nautilus — Вывод файлов из разных мест в одном окне

Tags: ubuntu

Есть ли возможность вывести в одном окне Nautilus'а переданный список файлов (возможно из разных директорий)?
Т. е. есть условный JSON-файл:

```
{
  "files": [
    "~/Hello_world.rs",
    "~/Books/*",
    ...
  ]
}
```

И хотелось бы увидеть их в удобном едином окне <s>to rule them all</s>.

Если нельзя, то подскажите способ сделать это в какой-либо оболочке/менеджере.

Спасибо.